Моментальное изменение качества видео DASH
this.dsh.setQualityFor('video', 1);

Так меняю качество видео по технологии dash. Но качество меняется не сразу, сперва проигрывает то что успело погрузиться до смены параметра.
Вопрос в том, как заставить поменять качество сразу. Или не сразу, а как только будут получены(подгружены) данные для перехода на указанное качество пользователем
